# Rally Lookback API: Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, rest, rally, lookbackapi

I am trying to get data from Rally LookBack API for my Rally Instance. My company instance is behind SSO and I have tried all the method of bypassing it with credentials, but nothing seems to be working.

In Lookback API, it is said that we can use an API key for authentication. So I tried the code below from POST Man, but I got the `500:Internal Server Error`, with out any further information on the error. Can someone please help me with this.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/5985761382/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find='_ProjectHierarchy':12506089503,'__At':'current'}));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
request.Accept = "application/json";

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + "<Rally API Key>");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass the api key is using the zsessionid header:

```
request.Headers.Add("zsessionid", "<Rally API Key>");
```